# Where is the "search" line in my resolv.conf coming from?

Tags: linux, hostname, resolv.conf

This is what my resolv.conf looks like:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 46.38.225.230
nameserver 46.38.252.230
search megasrv.de
```

It has a `search megasrv.de` line in there (and the dns resolvers). This is presumably so you can look up other servers from this provider just by their random hostname.

However, this is useless since I set my own hostnames. Because of that, I'd like to change this either to my domain, so the output of `hostname -f` is correct.

However, it is not clear to me where this line is coming from. All the files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolvconf.d/` are empty, except for the warning above. Yet after editing the files, the come back when I do `resolvconf -u`

Comment: Depending on distribution and other things, the setting can be altered in different places. eg: NetworkManager provides places to override DNS servers and domains. Directly changing isc dhclient's settings (if it's the DHCP used) with supersede domain-name would also result in changing this file. There are many other possibilities

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I think it's being set via dhcp. but I'm really not sure how to change it then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dhcp, it's coming from it you can change it from `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`